# Is there a way to specify a program to do a function once it iterated through an entire for loop, within another for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, printing

Newbie Python user here.  I am trying have a program compare dictionary rows received from a .csv file with dictReader, with my own dictionary data.  My program will take each row from the csv file and compare it with each column of my data to find a match.  Once a row is found where all the data matches, it will print out the key of that row, which is "name".

My problem is, I cannot find a way to tell my program to do that.  I put a break within an if statement within the nested for loop, so if a column doesn't match, it immediately moves to the next "name" row.  If I point print() at the end of the nested for loop, it will just print the name however many times a column is matched.  I just want the name printed once, IF all columns are matched...(so like, if it makes it to the end of the for loop)

```
with open(f"databases/{argv[1]}", "r") as dna_database:
    data = csv.DictReader(dna_database)
    for row in data:
        for column in dna:
            if dna[column] != int(row[column]):
                break
            print(row["name"])
    dna_database.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `else` clause of the `for` loop:

```py
with open(f"databases/{argv[1]}", "r") as dna_database:
    data = csv.DictReader(dna_database)
    for row in data:
        for column in dna:
            if dna[column] != int(row[column]):
                break
        else:
            print(row["name"])
```

The `else` clause is triggered when the `for` loop is *not* exited prematurely, i.e. "if it makes it to the end of the for loop".

> #### [The `for`-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)
>
> When the items are exhausted [..], the suite in the `else` clause, if present, is executed, and the loop terminates.

Comment: Ahh. Was not aware that an else statement could be used with a for loop.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: the `else` clause in `for` and `while` are very confusing compared to `if`, If the `if fails you  do the `else`, but with `for` and `while` if no break happens you **also** do the `else:`, a different keyword would be a lot better, and a case for the `break` in the loop

Answer (score 0):

You use a context manager so no need to call `close()`

```
with open(f"databases/{argv[1]}", "r") as dna_database:
    data = csv.DictReader(dna_database)
    for row in data:
        found = True
        for column in dna:
            if dna[column] != int(row[column]):
                found = False
                break
        if found:
            print(row["name"])
            break # stop: for row
```

Comment: Thank you!  Great use of boolean.  I will put this in the problem solving grey matter.